# Python: Selenium ChromeDriver opens blank page ('data:,')

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use Selenium (3.141.0) with ChromeDriver (87.0.4280) to access a page. When accessed manually, it brings me to a policy page (different URL) where you have to hit 'Ok' before continuing to the site. *Edit* This is using Win 10 and I have the folder with the chromedriver on PATH.

When using the following code, I'm able to get to the policy page with the ("--headless") option but without it I get a blank page with 'data:,' in the URL and nothing else loads. I've tried accessing straight from the policy page and the site URL but they both get stuck when the webdriver is created. Am I missing something? I'm open to any suggestions, thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver_path = 'D:\....\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= driver_path, options= chrome_options)
driver.get(...) # left out the url
```

[This is the output page I get without using ("--headless")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9dfq.png)

Comment: `chromedriver.exe` on Linux? Which OS?

Comment: @vitaliis Win 10 sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough, I realized it was because my Chrome Developer tools had become disabled. Not sure how but when I re-enabled them, it worked perfectly again. Weird.